# Extract the same code of an advice

Tags: java, aspectj

I have two advices:

```
public aspect LogAspect {
    before() : execution(@Log * *(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        String className = thisJoinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        String methodName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String startInfoMessage = String.format("%s.%s: execution started", className, methodName);
        logger.info(startInfoMessage);
    }

    after() : execution(@Log * *(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        String className = thisJoinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        String methodName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String endInfoMessage = String.format("%s.%s: execution's finished", className, methodName);
        logger.info(startInfoMessage);
    }
}
```

There's wierd code duplication. I tried to extract the same body into a separted method as follows

```
 private String getInfoMessage(String pattern){
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(thisJoinPoint.getClass());
        String className = thisJoinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        String methodName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String infoMessage = String.format(pattern, className, methodName);
        return infoMessage;
    }
```

But it doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know about `thisJoinPoint`  outside of an advice. What's the solution for those things?

Comment: Try passing thisJoinPoint as a method param. If that doesn't work, i don't think anything else will.From the docs:

> The thisJoinPoint variable can only be used in the context of advice,
> just like this can only be used in the context of non-static methods
> and variable initializers . https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Sounds reasonable, thank you.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. BTW, how do you yourself avoiding such a duplication?

Comment: My logging aspect is less verbose, so there is no need to make it more DRY. I used around my logging pointcut